# Build actionscript 3 project to exe

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

As simple as the title,
I want my project to run from an executable file rather than an swf

I know about the 'create projector' option but the latest flash player has this option grayed out.

I use flash develop if it matters

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use AIR with Captive Runtime to create an exe from your Flash app.

Comment: Will it require people who'll use the app to firstly install flex for it to work or something?

Comment: They will have to install the AIR runtime.

Comment: @ethrbunny Ah that sucks are you sure that there's no other way? I've even seen a few games that did that, no AIR at all, just an exe

Comment: @ethrbunny You couldn't be more wrong.  The use of AIR with Captive Runtime does not require users to install the AIR Runtime. It packages the AIR runtime with your app; so everything is self contained.  Since the feature was introduced It is the most common way to deploy AIR apps; especially on mobile devices.

Comment: @Don Using AIR with Captive Runtime will not require users to install Flex.  Flex is a development SDK whose code is compiled into the a final SWF; so the users will not have to install it on their machines to make use of a Flash Platform app (whether using AIR or the browser based Flash Player)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Flextras mentioned in the comments you can distribute your AIR app as an exe+dmg by packaging it as a captive runtime.

This will bundle the AIR runtime alongside your app and will **not** require the user to have anything else installed. Everything needed will be contained in the application binary.

You can use `adt` to build your exe,

http://www.tricedesigns.com/2011/08/10/air-3-0-captive-runtime/

```
adt -package SIGNING_OPTIONS? -target bundle SIGNING_OPTIONS? <output-package> ( <app-desc> FILE-OPTIONS | <input-package> )
```

More info,

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f709e16db131e43659b9-8000.html

You can also build it right from Flash Builder 4.6+

http://houseofbilz.com/archives/2011/10/11/captive-runtime-packaging-in-air-3-0/

If you do have dependencies you can also package your AIR app as a native desktop installer,

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS789ea67d3e73a8b22388411123785d839c-8000.html

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air3-install-and-deployment-options.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader

Answer (score 1):

If you run your .swf file using Flash Player 10.1, you can find Create Projector option still available. It looks like Adobe wants all the desktop applications to use AIR SDK and thus this option to Create Projector is greyed out. I am still stuck with fp 10.1 because of this.

Comment: Yeah that's probably what they're doing, I used AIR now and it works great, just like I wanted it

Comment: If your app doesn't makes use of any AIR api.. you don't need to convert it to AIR app, as the setup size will be huge compared to that of the Projector created from Flash Player.

Comment: True, it is a lot larger,it added about 40 Megabytes to the total size of the game which is only 79kb as an swf, but I need to use the flash player 11 as my project relies on it so I guess I have no other choice

Answer (score 0):

Projector Export (Flash CC)

Projectors are Flash files that contain both the published SWF and Flash Player. Projectors can play like an ordinary application, without the need for a web browser, the Flash Player plugin, or Adobe AIR.

About this Extension:

Projectors were deprecated from Flash Pro CC, however, using this Extension you can now publish your Flash content from Flash Pro CC as a standalone application.

The exported Projector from Flash CC will be an .EXE file on windows and an .APP file on Mac, that can be played on any Windows and Mac machines respectively even without an installed Flash Player or plug-in.

How to Install:

Download the ZXP extension file and install it via the Extension Manager CC. (You must have Flash Pro CC installed on your system before using this extension)

How to Use:

1. Open the Fla file in Flash Pro CC that you wish to export as a projector.
2. Navigate to Commands Menu -> Export as Projector
3. Choose the location for saving your projector and click on ‘Select Folder’.

Download here:
[https://nipunasthana.wordpress.com/projectorforflashcc](https://nipunasthana.wordpress.com/projectorforflashcc/)

Answer (score -1):

1. open swf file with flash player
2. file -> create projector 

   so easy...

Comment: Please have a look at the question again. The OP stated that the 'create projector' option is not available to them. So, I how far does your solution help the OP?